# NULL fields after executing LENGTH(email_address)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I got a problem, i wanted to obtain the **maximum length of a field** because i wanted to know if there was fields that exceeded the size established for that field, for example : varchar2(20)

I am using oracle 11g, take a look at this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DdWM.jpg

So, i did this query:

```
    SELECT
    hp.party_name                              
  , hca.account_number
  , hca.cust_account_id                        
 -- , hcsu.LOCATION customer_site_name
  , hcas.cust_acct_site_id                     
  , hcp.phone_number
  , hcp.email_address
  , hl.address1
  , hl.address2
  , hl.address3
  , hl.address4
  , hl.city
  , hl.province
  , hl.postal_code
  , hcas.status                                
  , DECODE( hcas.attribute5, 'PUP', 'Y', 'N' ) 
  , hca.status                                 
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca
INNER JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas ON hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_party_sites hps ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_locations hl ON hps.location_id = hl.location_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_parties hp ON hps.party_id = hp.party_id
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            owner_table_id
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'PHONE' then phone_number end) phone_number
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'EMAIL' then email_address end) email_address
        FROM hz_contact_points
        WHERE status = 'A'
        AND primary_flag = 'Y'
        AND owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES'
        AND contact_point_type IN ('EMAIL','PHONE')
        AND length (phone_number) > 40
        GROUP BY 
            owner_table_id
    ) hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id 
WHERE hcas.status = 'A'
AND hps.status = 'A'
AND hca.status = 'A'
AND hca.account_number = ''
;
```

I put this condition **"AND length (phone_number) > 40"** but it is not working because it shows null fields, why?

Take a look at this:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRKNe.jpg)

Also, is this condition okay?

```
hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id
```

Can you please help me with this?

PS: i am using SQL DEVELOPER and oracle database 11g

Comment: Please don't post (links to) images of table structures, code or query results, use text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you modified the query doesn’t look good. You added a `WHERE` clause to a subquery taht is used to recover the user email and phone number from table `hz_contact_point`. Now it looks like the subquery does not return anything, and related’fields are `NULL` in the results (if you were using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, you would have no results at all),

If you just need to control or format your output, don’t modify the subquery : it might break the logic. Use the main query. For example, the below sample replaces the phone number with `NULL` if it has more than 40 chars.

```
SELECT
     hp.party_name
    , hca.account_number
    ...
    , CASE WHEN LENGTH(hcp.phone_number) > 40 THEN NULL ELSE hcp.phone_number END
    , hcp.email_address
...
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!
Dude, i got this error when i tried to filfer the table in order to find all the information related to an account_number (in SQL DEVELOPER)
https://imgur.com/a/ddgz2DA
WHY?

Comment: How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You left join that subquery aliased `hcp`, so if there are no matching rows from `hcp` for some rows of the other tables inner joined before, the values from `hcp` are `NULL` for these rows.

But if `phone_number` is declared as `varchar2(40)` you won't find any phone numbers with `length(phone_number) > 40`. They would have been rejected if some one tried to insert them.